# Scala parsing with alternative parsers with parseAll not working as expected

Tags: scala, parsing

Let's say I have this simple parser:

```
  object SimpleBooleanParser extends RegexParsers {
    def identifier: Parser[QueryExpression] = """[0-9]""".r ^^ { str => QueryLiteral(str.trim) }

    def andExpression: Parser[QueryExpression] = rep1sep(identifier, "&") ^^ {
      case Seq(singleTerm) => singleTerm
      case termsList => termsList.reduceLeft(QueryAnd)
    }

    def orExpression: Parser[QueryExpression] = rep1sep(identifier, "|") ^^ {
      case Seq(singleTerm) => singleTerm
      case termsList => termsList.reduceLeft(QueryOr)
    }

    def parseExpression(input: String): ParseResult[QueryExpression] = parseAll(orExpression | andExpression, input)
  }

  def parseQuerySimple(query: String): QueryExpression = {
    SimpleBooleanParser.parseExpression(query) match {
      case SimpleBooleanParser.Success(result, _) =>
        return result
      case SimpleBooleanParser.Failure(msg, next) =>
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          s"Failed to parse '$query' near '${next.pos.longString}': $msg")
    }
  }
```

The following call succeeds:

```
Query.parseQuerySimple("3|4|5")
```

However, this one throws the IllegalArgumentException

```
Query.parseQuerySimple("1&2&3")

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to parse '1&2&3' near '1&2&3
 ^': end of input expected
```

If I change the definition of parseExpression to this:

```
def parseExpression(input: String): ParseResult[QueryExpression] = {
  val parseResult1 = parseAll(orExpression, input)
  parseResult1 match {
    case SimpleBooleanParser.Success(result, _) =>
      parseResult1
    case SimpleBooleanParser.Failure(_, _) =>
      val parseResult2 = parseAll(andExpression, input)
      parseResult2
  }
}
```

, then both of the unit tests succeed.

In the latter case, I am simply trying each of the two parsers one at a time.  Why does this work, but parseAll(orExpression | andExpression, input) does not?  Shouldn't that do the same thing?

Comment: On a first glance: you match "eagerly" `identifier`, so code enters `[0-9]|` branch, and then finds that the next symbol is `&` which fails. I'd would suspect the way backtracking is handled here, and check whether it is here in the first place. And the code looks like `scala-parser-combinators` which appear in outdated tutorials: this library has some warts and offers neither outstanding performance (like fastparse would) nor sane API (all these `^^`).